# Dropzone.js : stop adding to queue when event triggered

Tags: javascript, file-upload, dropzone.js

I'm using Dropzone.js and would like to stop adding files to the queue when a certain event is triggered (maxfilesreached) to be precise.

Let's say I've chosen 15 files in my 'Browse' window, but my maxFiles limit is 10. At the 11th, a maxfilesreached event is fired. At that point I want the 5 remaining files not to be added to the queue.

Here is what I have for now :

```
init : function() {
                    this.on('maxfilesreached', function(e){
                        alert("I want to stop adding stuff to the queue here");
                    });
```

I want to cancel all future additions to the queue when too many files have been chosen already. How can I proceed ?

Thanks in advance

A.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I should have know. RTFM. Shame upon me and my family.

From the [FAQ](https://github.com/enyo/dropzone/wiki/FAQ#how-can-i-limit-the-number-of-files), this is the correct way to do that :

```
this.on('maxfilesexceeded',function(file) {
    this.removeFile(file);
    alert("Oh wait you've exceeded your quota.");
});
```

I will now go and wear a cone of shame.

Answer (score -1):

try this,

```
var myDropzone = new Dropzone("#dropzone", {
  acceptedFiles: ".jpeg,.jpg,.png,.gif,.TIF,.JPEG,.JPG,.PNG,.GIF",
  addRemoveLinks: true,
  parallelUploads: 2,
  thumbnailWidth: "80",
  thumbnailHeight: "80",
  dictCancelUpload: "Cancel",
  autoProcessQueue: false
});
```

where `#dropzone` is your dropzone id whether it is a form id or div id. `parallelUploads: 5,` is to set maximum files to uplaod.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but this option is to limit the number of files uploaded at the same time. So there can be more files in the queue, and they will all be uploaded (if n<maxFiles).

Comment: I tried it but it's not doing what I need. I just want that if maxFiles is reached, all additional files won't be added to the queue. I've tried `myDropzone.removeFile(file)` but it says _too much recursion_ in the JS console.